# How can i get sympy to use Latex to render equations?

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I am trying to solve some equations using sympy, and I want to get a good looking image in the console. I am using Spyder without annaconda in dark mode, which shows a really ugly equation, because the foreground colour is still black, instead of white.

When I try to change the foreground colour using 'mathjax'

```
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax', forecolor='White')
sympy.init_printing(use_latex=True, forecolor='White')
```

It shows no difference. Then when i replace 'mathjax' with True, the Ipython console breaks and seems to run an infinite loop.

I read somewhere that in order to change foreground colour, it requires a Latex installation, because it will otherwise render with matplotlib, which can't change the colour. I currently think that the problem is that sympy doesnt seem to recognise my latex installation, and is therefore not working. Why it will render the ugly version in mathjax, I have no idea.

I am currently using:
spyder 4.1 without annaconda (so just a pip install),
python 3.7.5,
Ipython 7.10.1,
sympy 1.6.0, and
TeXLive for Latex

Hopefully Someone can help me with my problem, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've managed to solve the problem and I wanted to post the answer in case someone else has this problem. In short, sympy seems to have a problem with texlive. I installed miktex on my machine and the code snippets now actually change the colour. Hopefully this is useful to someone in the future.

Comment: I think there have been changes to this since sympy 1.1 so I also suggest trying sympy 1.6 (current version)

Comment: I did update sympy as I was trying stuff out. For some reason i forgot to add the new version number in the post. Still only works with miktex though